# How to draw human face using canvas object in android?

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw human face when face recognise using android vision API.
But i dont know how to draw human face using Canvas object?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlgCE.jpg)

Please check attached screenshot for more unserstanding.
When face recognise using Vision API,I am drawing rectangle around face using canvas.drawrect(left, top, right, bottom, paint).

But i want to draw a view like attached image.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and doesn't describe what you've tried to do or what you've looked at. My suggestion would be, if you are using the android vision API, have a look at the documentation first, try something and then come back with a better, more precise question

Here's some code you can look at to start off with, taken from :
https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial

[image]

Comment: I have attached 1 more screenshot.where you can see rectangle around face. But i want to draw like attached screenshot when face detect.